# JQuery / AJAX delete item from database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make a CRUD in jquery/ajax/php for learning purposes. 
But I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong with the delete part.

My goal is to delete an record from the database without refreshing the page.

Ajax function:

```
    $(document).on('click', '.deleteOrder', function(e){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log('Clicked order: ' + id);

    $.ajax({
        type:   'POST',
        url:    'orders/deleteorder/',
        data:   {
            orderId: id
        },
        success: function(data){
            updateOrder(e);
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log('error');
        }
    });
});
```

Php function:

```
    public function deleteOrder(){
    $orderId = $_POST['id'];
    $count=$this->connection->prepare("DELETE FROM orders WHERE orderNumber = :number");
    $count->bindParam(":number",$orderId,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $count->execute();
    echo 'Finished order ' . $orderId;
}
```

Comment: print_r() the $this->Connection after the prepare statement. Should give you the query. Also have you checked if the function `deleteOrder` gets the correct $orderId.

Comment: @bIgBoY For some reason if I want to use echo's or print r's it doesn't show up on the page. So I can't check wether it gets the ID in php

Comment: check the network tab for the xhr request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check the delete function called or not through ajax, in browser Network tab (you see this when clicking F12 button in browser)

Answer (score -1):

you did not call  deleteOrder function .

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10554450)

Comment: I did call the function in "url:    'orders/deleteorder/' " but that has nothing to do with this question like @Tarion said.

Comment: if (isset(orderId)){  deleteOrder(); } //Add  this in your ajax file at the top